# Python, if a or b and c , not working as expected

Tags: python, conditional-statements, vlc

I'm stuck with an issue that feels so simple yet I can't figure it out.

The following example returns 'else' as expected:

```
a, b, c = False, False, True
if a or b and c:
    print('if')
else:
    print('else')
```

now, if I apply the same logic to my project as done below:

```
import time, vlc

def play_sound(path):
    _ = vlc.MediaPlayer(path)
    _.play()

def check_commands(audio_capture):
if 'who' or 'what' in audio_capture and "are you" in audio_capture:
    play_sound("ResponseToCommands/response_A.mp3")
    time.sleep(2.2)

elif audio_capture == "are you ready":
    play_sound("ResponseToCommands/response_B.mp3")

check_commands('are you ready')
time.sleep(5) # optional
check_commands('what are you')
```

I would expect the same results. However, I keep getting response_A.mp3 instead of first response_B and then response_A.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: `("a" in string or "b" in string) and "c" in string`

Comment: Non-empty strings are truthy in Python.

Comment: That last bit was the issue! you're quick mate, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition is parsed the same as

```
if 'who' or ('what' in audio_capture and "are you" in audio_capture):
```

`'who'` is a truthy value, so the entire condition is true without ever needing to check for values in `audio_capture`.

What you wanted was

```
if ('who' in audio_capture or 'what' in audio_capture) and "are you" in audio_capture:
```

`in` does not "distribute" over `or` like  multiplication distributes over addition.

Answer (score 1):

In first example simply writing if a or b and c worked because that simply means if a is True or b is True and c is True. But you can't use same for the example not having boolean value
Thus, solution is simple

```
def check_commands(audio_capture):
    if 'who' in audio_capture or 'what' in audio_capture and "are you" in audio_capture:
        play_sound("ResponseToCommands/response_A.mp3")
        time.sleep(2.2)
```

This should simply work